# Why do I keep getting this error(cannot be resolved)?

Tags: java, android

In one of my classes I am getting this error: game cannot be resolved or is not a field, and when I launch the application it says cannot open please try again, why do I keep getting this error, is there something wrong with the R.java?

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

Grid myView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myView = new Grid(this);
    myView.setGame(new Game());
    setContentView(myView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);//error occurring here
    return true;
}}
```

r.java

```
/* AUTO-GENERATED FILE.  DO NOT MODIFY.
*
* This class was automatically generated by the
* aapt tool from the resource data it found.  It
* should not be modified by hand.
*/

package com.example.applicationprogrammingassignment;

public final class R {
public static final class anim {
    public static final int slide_in_left=0x7f040000;
    public static final int slide_out_left=0x7f040001;
}
public static final class attr {
}
public static final class dimen {
    /**  Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. 

     Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
     screen margins) for sw720dp devices (e.g. 10" tablets) in landscape here.

     */
    public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f050000;
    public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f050001;
}
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
}
public static final class id {
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f090003;
    public static final int btnHelp=0x7f090002;
    public static final int btnPlay=0x7f090000;
    public static final int btnScore=0x7f090001;
}
public static final class layout {
    public static final int activity_main=0x7f030000;
}
public static final class menu {
    public static final int main=0x7f080000;
}
public static final class string {
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f060001;
    public static final int app_name=0x7f060000;
    public static final int hello_world=0x7f060002;
}
public static final class style {
    /** 
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.


    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.

    API 11 theme customizations can go here. 

    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.

    API 14 theme customizations can go here. 
     */
    public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f070000;
    /**  Application theme. 
    All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. 
     */
    public static final int AppTheme=0x7f070001;
}
}
```

Comment: As you can see there is no such resource "game" in your R.java

Comment: getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu, menu); ? getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); ? Please provide your menu.xml src.

Comment: @Stan, getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu, menu) ? No, he will end up with "R.menu cannot be resolved to a variable". user3267882, see my answer, create a game.xml or use the main.xml inside res/menu...

Comment: @2Dee only in 1st case.

Comment: @Stan, that's what I said, our comments edits cross-fired ;)

Answer (score 0):

R.java is compiled automatically each time you modify your resources in the `res` directory, but it will not be updated if there is bug in one of your xml files.

Check all your XML files carefully for errors (Lint should mark errors for you automatically). Also, check any 9 patches you have to make sure they are valid. You can temporarily remove `.9` from the name to see if the problem was with the 9 patch format. I have had cases where some of the border pixels in my 9 patch were not pure black or pure white, and that caused R.java not to get updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you posted your entire R file, it seems you haven't defined a game menu, the only menu found is main :

```
public static final class menu {
    public static final int main=0x7f080000;
}
```

You need to either use R.menu.main if you correctly defined menu items in it, or create a game.xml menu file inside res/menu.

Comment: You created game.xml inside your res/menu folder ? That should do it, but you may need to clean/rebuild your project...

Comment: Then check Tenfour04's answer, you probably have an error somewhere in your res folder (xml files, 9patch images) that is preventing your R.java from being updated...